# Sitemesh + Struts2 + Velocity: Decorators cannot access the context's objects

Tags: struts2, velocity, sitemesh

I have a struts2 web app using velocity. I am integrating Sitemesh to the project.

The decorators are called properly but for some reasons, the objects placed in the context via the toolbox configuration (velocaity related) are not being loaded.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

In the web.xml configuratiration file, I omitted to specify the init-param for the VelocityDecoratorServlet so that it would load the app's velocity tools specified in the toolbox.xml

sitemesh-velocity
        com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.velocity.VelocityDecoratorServlet
    
            org.apache.velocity.toolbox
            /WEB-INF/toolbox.xml